# Replacing variables in external file through playbook

Tags: deployment, ansible, yaml

I would like to use variables (vars.yaml) to replace the content in a config file (config.yaml) and automatise the process in the playbook (playbook.yaml). But I can't found a type of process that automaticly search for vars inside an external file through the playbook.yaml.

My files look like this :
vars.yaml

```
---
var1: content1
var2: content2
var3: content3
```

config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: 1
 
datasources:
  - name: {{ var1 }}
    type: {{ var2 }}
    access: proxy
    url: {{ var3 }}
```

playbook.yaml:

```
---
- name: Deploy
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: ./vars.yaml

    - name: Update config file
      # Something to replace all vars in the config file using the content of vars.yaml
```

Can you help me and tell me if there is something possible instead of doing a regex for each variable ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file with the unresolved variables is actually a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html). Let's name it this way

```yaml
shell> cat config.yaml.j2
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
  - name: {{ var1 }}
    type: {{ var2 }}
    access: proxy
    url: {{ var3 }}
```

Use the *template* module to update *config.yaml*, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars: vars.yaml
    - name: Update config file
      template:
        src: config.yaml.j2
        dest: config.yaml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat config.yaml
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
  - name: content1
    type: content2
    access: proxy
    url: content3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I went over it in the doc but I hadn't understood the concept like that....

It helps me a lot